# How do I vertically center an image with a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center-align an image and a floated-left paragraph. I need to float the paragraph as opposed to the image because I want the image to appear below the paragraph on mobile devices. Here is my code:

```css
img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h3 {
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  p {
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Header</h3>
<p>texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext
  texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttextt exttexttextte xttexttexttex ttexttexttext texttexttextt exttexttextte xttexttexttex ttexttexttextte xttexttexttextt exttexttexttext texttexttexttex ttexttexttextte xttexttexttextt exttex
  ttexttexttexttex ttexttexttexttexttext</p>
<img src="w3css.gif">
<h3>Header</h3>
```

Right now, the image lines up with the top of the paragraph, but I want the image and paragraph to be center aligned with each other. Looking for a CSS solution here, thanks in advance.

Comment: flex or grid could help for the layout (inline-block/table-cell too)  , float is unable to deal with vertical-align

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this CSS to vertically align any element.   I tried to make a snippet but I wasn't exactly sure what you want the outcome to look like, so I figured I'd just give you the 3 lines of CSS needed to vert-center anything.

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex if you don't want to set a relative position.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-flow: row;
```

Answer (score 0):

`flex` and `grid` can help *(body is used for the container )*

`flex` example *( usefull https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ )*

```css
img {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap
  }
  h3 {
    min-width: 90%;
    flex-grow: 1
  }
  p {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Header</h3>
<p>texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext
  texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttextt exttexttextte xttexttexttex ttexttexttext texttexttextt exttexttextte xttexttexttex ttexttexttextte xttexttexttextt exttexttexttext texttexttexttex ttexttexttextte xttexttexttextt exttex
  ttexttexttexttex ttexttexttexttexttext</p>
<img src="w3css.gif">
<h3>Header</h3>
```

`grid` example *(usefull https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ )*

```css
img {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
  }
  h3 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Header</h3>
<p>texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext
  texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttextt exttexttextte xttexttexttex ttexttexttext texttexttextt exttexttextte xttexttexttex ttexttexttextte xttexttexttextt exttexttexttext texttexttexttex ttexttexttextte xttexttexttextt exttex
  ttexttexttexttex ttexttexttexttexttext</p>
<img src="w3css.gif">
<h3>Header</h3>
```